# Got stuck in the following Sturm-Liouville problems

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, greens-function

I have got stuck in two Strum-Liouville problems.

$1. \quad y''+y=-1,\quad y(0)=0,\quad y(\pi)+y(\dfrac{\pi}{2})=0$, Now

$y''+y=0$ and $y(0)=0 \implies \phi_1(x)=\sin x$ while

$y''+y=0$ and $y(\pi)+y(\dfrac{\pi}{2})=0\implies \phi_2(x)=\cos x +\sin x$

So the Green's Function that I am getting is :

$G(x,\xi)=\begin{cases}\sin x(\cos \xi+\sin \xi),\quad x\lt\xi\\\sin \xi (\cos x+\sin x),\quad x\gt\xi\end{cases}$

and the solution I am getting :

$y(x)=\cos x+2\sin x-1$ but the answer given is $y(x)=\cos x+3\sin x-1$. Can somebody show what is wrong and give the correct solution.

$2. \quad y''+y=0,\quad y(0)=y(1),\quad y'(0)=y'(1)$. Find the Green's Function for this problem.

The two linearly independent solutions of the associated homogeneous equation that I got after putting boundary conditions are

$\phi_1(x)=\sin(1-x)+\sin x$ and $\phi_2(x)=\cos(1-x)+\cos x$. But then I am getting the Wronskian $W(\phi_1,\phi_2)=\phi_1\phi_2'-\phi_1'\phi_2$ as $0$. But I know that the Green's function exist. Can someone help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the condition $y(\pi)+y(\pi/2)=0$.

Comment: @Did, That's what is given, even I felt it is a bit conc. Do you feel that the condition is wrong ?

Comment: @Amzoti, After obtaining Green's Function, I substituted and integrated from $0$ to x and x to $\pi$

Comment: No I "feel" that your answer does not satisfy it.

Comment: @Amzoti, I have added the steps, have a look.

Comment: @Amzoti, for the first one even in matlab and wolframalpha.com its giving the same answer.

Comment: @Amzoti, even in the second one, I am getting what I got previously. One doubt I have is, when we apply the 1st b.c we get a relation in A and B (coeff). Let us say that in this case I express B in terms of A and substitute in the soln to get my $\phi_1(x)$. Now my doubt is next time for the 2nd condition again when we get a relation bw A and B, which one do I express in terms of the other (B in terms of A or vice versa) ?? I did B in terms of A again to get what I got. Will it make a difference if I do the other way round ? ie will I get what u r telling if I express A in terms of B